# two gains in audio context is somehow connected each other

Tags: java, processing

I initialized my two different gains, hooked up with the different filters and connected to my Audio Context(ac)

```
gain1 = new Gain(ac, 1, gain1Glide);
gain2 = new Gain(ac, 1, gain2Glide);

filter.addInput(gain1);
statusFilter.addInput(gain2);
ac.out.addInput(filter);
ac.out.addInput(statusFilter);

gain1 -> filter       \
                       -> ac(AudioContext)
gain2 -> statusFilter /
```

Problem: When I change my gain2 (somehow it changes the glide of the gain1) as well. And it sounds noisy.

Why is gain1 is affected by gain2? And how do we fix it?

Thanks